# DS3231 Question

Tags: component-selection, rtc

Can someone help me understand the differences between:
"[Adafruit DS3231 Precision RTC Breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3013)" and one of these generic breakout modules, "[DS3231 AT24C32 IIC RTC Module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q7NZTQS)"?

Why I would choose one over the other?

I am making a watch using the DS3231 and eventually I plan on putting all of my chips, LEDs, and a battery holder onto one custom board, but I don't quite see why there are so many different form factors for these boards when essentially they all provide the same function.

Comment: The second one has an additional eeprom chip onboard which is quite unrelated to the main functionality of DS3231. it's just there because the designer thought "OK someone is going to log data using this DS3231 so let's put a super cheap eeprom IC here". I would go for adafruit one because they have better experience designing modules than unknown designers and we can trust them that they use original parts. finally, they have offered a lot of free libraries to hobbyist so this purchase would be supportive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Adafruit module:**

- Manufactured by a trusted designer with *original parts*, libraries and regularly updated walk-throughs to use the modules. The exact schematic and PCB layout is also provided.
- Expensive; compared to the other module.

**Unknown module:**

- Made by unknown manufacturers with no library, walk-through or website.
- Not guaranteed to use the original part and for a "precision" timer, it's quite important.
- The design may vary between manufacturers or later versions. For example you may find an exact looking module but with another eeprom chip or another default addressing or even different pin order.
- It has an on-board eeprom IC. that would ease the burden of wiring another IC if you want to log data into a memory with timestamps or simply need more storage.
- It's cheap.

---

**Personal experience:**

See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/533924/lm75-i2c-bad-temperature-read-problem/535150#535150) question I asked a few months ago while digging through some fake temperature ICs.