# Why SBC contain EEPROM?

Tags: eeprom, sbc

I have nanopc t2 SBC, its software is open source. However, it has an EEPROM. Why? Do they put some confidential information on it? What if I plan to redesign that board, will I need the contents of the EEPROM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EEPROM in the schematics, 24AA025, has unique MAC address as well, that can be used for Ethernet and WIFI. The EEPROM can be used as an extra space, if needed. Kernel and uboot goes in EMMC, not into EEPROM.

Comment: Wow, that is a very advanced trick indeed. I wonder the EEPROM in DS3231 is as clever: 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/596067/ds3231-question

Comment: I think your boards differ because there is something configuring the board in EEPROM

Comment: @FindOut_Quran , Aha, thanks.. Raspi4, too, has configuration in EEPROM for boot media and etc. They supply a utility to access EEPROM. Anyway, thanks for bringing up "nanopc t2". I was having troubles with Raspi4 graphics, and looking for a new platform. ... I don't think EEP has "nanoboot", it is a dangerous idea.